# Searching in table jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have made a script to find strings in table. When it finds it shows the row otherwise hide it.
It is working perfectly in Chrome but it is some what lagging in Firefox and Internet Explorer. Is this code good or can it be better ?

```
$("#searchValue").keyup(function() {

  var table = $(this).siblings('table').not(':hidden');
  var name = $("#searchValue").val();
  if (name === "") {
    $(table).find('tr').show();
    $(table).trigger('update');
  }
  else {
    name = name.toLowerCase();
    var trs = $(table).find('tr').not(':first');
    trs.each(function() {
      var tr = $(this);
      var count = ($(tr).children('td').length);
      var suc = -1;
      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var state = $(tr).children("td").eq(i).html();
        state = state.toLowerCase();
        if (state.match(name)) {
          suc = 1;
        }
        else if (suc !== 1) {
          suc = 0;
        }
      }
      if (suc === 1) {
        $(tr).show();
      }
      else {
        $(tr).hide();
      }
    });

    $(table).trigger('update');
  }
});
```

Table :

```
  <table id='tableProject' class='tablesorter'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Project ID</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Max Hours</th>
            <th>Achieved</th>
            <th>Difference</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you provide a table sample also

Comment: Is it possible for you to use DataTables?

Comment: few more records so that we can play around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.eq()` within the for loop could *potentially* (not positive) be the cause of your performance issues.  Within each `tr` you are saying "now iterate over the DOM multiple times and find `td` with this index".

Also IMO, using a for loop  within `.each()` is redundant.

Avoid using `.eq()` in this scenario and simply use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/FLYRv/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#searchValue").keyup(function () {
        var table = $(this).siblings('table').not(':hidden'),
            name = $("#searchValue").val().toLowerCase();

        if (!name) {
            $(table).find('tr').show();
            $(table).trigger('update');
        } else {
            var trs = $(table).find('tbody tr');

            trs.each(function () {
                var tr = $(this),
                    results = null;

                results = tr.find('td').filter(function () {
                    return $(this).html().toLowerCase().match(name);
                });

                if (!results.length) {
                    tr.hide()
                } else {
                    tr.show();
                }
            });
            $(table).trigger('update');
        }
    });
});
```